# More efficient way to write this simple Python non-sequential number generator?

Tags: python, algorithm

Is there a more efficient way to write this so it's not looping from 1 to n (which hangs on n == 2**32):

```
def ns_num(n, seed, modulo, incrementor):
    assert n < modulo

    current = seed # some start value
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        current = (current + incrementor) % modulo

    return current

print ns_num(5, 3250, 87178291199, 17180131327)
print ns_num(2**32, 3250, 87178291199, 17180131327)
```

Comment: Yield current from inside the for loop.

Comment: The word "generator" in Python has a specific meaning. This function is **not** a generator.

Comment: @Jakob: huh?? you mean ns_num() should return during the first loop iteration?

Comment: @Mark: point well taken, but "generator" also has a more general meaning, especially when combined in a well-known phrase like "random number generator."

Comment: @LarsH, You're absolutely right. Just pointing out a possible source of confusion.

Comment: @Mark: ok. I mistakenly thought you were taking him to task for misusing the term.

Comment: @LarsH, I try very hard not to be judgemental about these things, we've all been there and most of the time it's just because you haven't been exposed to it yet. My tone was all wrong though, thanks for pointing it out - I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: This looks - almost - like an LCG. I hope you're not planning on using it to generate pseudorandom numbers?

Comment: @Nick, I am.  What would you recommend, then?  I want an injective function to generate pseudorandom numbers between 62^5 and 62^6 - 1.

Comment: @Bradford By injective you mean you want to be able to get any part of the sequence in O(1) time? I would use a block cipher, like this: http://blog.notdot.net/2007/9/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-2-Secure-permutations-with-block-ciphers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the same as

```
return (seed + (n - 1) * incrementor) % modulo
```

(Are you sure you want `n - 1`?  That's what you current code does.)

Comment: Good catch!  And thanks for the answer.  Don't know why I couldn't think about this.

Comment: @Bradford: Note that my code will give a different answer than yours for `n = 0`.  I still doubt you really want `n - 1` there.  Your code will give the same answer for `n = 0` and `n = 1`.